# UIView doesn't animate

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I want to animate the center of a UIView, and I did this in viewDidLoad:

```
_test.center = CGPointMake(100.0,100.0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 
        delay:5 
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
        animations:^{_test.center = CGPointMake(100.0,-100.0);} 
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

But when I run the code, the center of test view is already at 100,-100. Why it doesn't animate?

Comment: Move the code to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @Avi It works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move the code from your `viewDidLoad` to your `viewDidAppear`. In `viewDidLoad`, the `UIView` has been loaded, but it is not visually present yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using auto constraints which prevent animating views the way you are doing.

In order to fix this issue try these steps:

First:

Move your code to `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Second:

Do these steps before and after doing any animation to your view:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

     _test.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

     _test.center = CGPointMake(100.0,100.0);
     [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 
                           delay:5 
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
                      animations:^{_test.center = CGPointMake(100.0,-100.0);} 
                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                      }];

     [_test updateConstraints];

}
```